# Qt: qgraphicsitem drag and drop

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I have a problem with Qt. I want to drag an image and use of `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and dragenterevent but it doesnt appear in the console ?
but other function like   hoverEnterEvent work corectly???
here is the code:
please help?

```
class button : public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
public:
    button(const QPixmap &);
    button();
    void changepic( QPixmap,int ,int);
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*event);
    void dragenterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event){

        event->setAccepted(1);
       qDebug("drag");
    }
    void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event){
       qDebug("drop");
    }

    void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event){

           // do something
       // this->setPos(this->x()+10,this->y()+10);

             qDebug("k");

           QGraphicsItem::hoverMoveEvent(event);
       }
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
};
```

Comment: I think you're getting the concept of "drag and drop" (dragging an object from one place and "dropping" it into another) mixed up with the concept of using the mouse to move an item in your scene.

Answer (score 12):

Are you just wanting to be able to move a graphics item around your scene? If so, then all you need to do is set some flags for the item. For example,

```
setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
```

If you are actually trying to implement drag-and-drop onto your graphics item, you must call `setAcceptDrops(true)` for your item.

The reason for some of this extra work is that Qt, by default, is trying to optimize the performance of your scene. So you have to explicitly opt-in to some of these extra features. You are saying, "I know this will have a negative impact on performance, but I'm OK with that; I need this feature."

Comment: hi but where do i must write this flag? in constructor?

Comment: Yes, the constructor would be an ideal place. I think you can call them from anywhere--it would change the behavior at the point you call it. But if you want it "always on," the constructor is the best place.