# How to display a thumbnail on QGraphicsScene?

Tags: qt, thumbnails, qgraphicsscene

First, I draw a lot of QGraphicsItems on the QGraphicsScene. I want to show a thumbnail that can be dragged freely in the bottom right corner of the QGraphicsScene. What classes should I use? How do I use them?

Answer (score 0):

- Try to capture Mouse events on QGraphicsItems
- Option 1 : using mousemove calculated delta from older position to new and move your graphicsItem Accordingly.
- Option 2 : check QgraphicsItem support for drag events or not
  Check here [Qt: qgraphicsitem drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950820/qt-qgraphicsitem-drag-and-drop)